# Prove that the function $f(\bar{z})=e^{2\pi i z}$ is well-defined and that it is a group-homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism

Let the function $f:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to U_1$ be defined by $f(\bar{z})=e^{2\pi i z}$, where $U_1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^*:|z|=1\}$. Prove that this funcstion is well-defined and a that it is group-homomorphism.

---

**Well-defined:**

Suppose $\bar{a},\bar{b}\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $\bar{a}=\bar{b}$, so that $\bar{a},\bar{b}\in[0,1)$. Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $a>b$ which implies that $a$ can be written as $a=b+k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then we can see that:

$f(\bar{b})=e^{2\pi ib}=e^{2\pi i(a+k)}=e^{i(2\pi a+k2\pi)}=$
$\cos(2\pi a + k2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi a + k2\pi) =\cos(2\pi a)+i\sin(2\pi a)=$
$e^{2\pi ia}=f(\bar{a})$

We now have $\bar{a}=\bar{b}\implies f(\bar{a})=f(\bar{b})$, so $f$ is well-defined.

---

**Group-homomorphism:**

Suppose $\bar{a},\bar{b}\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, then:

$f(\bar{a}+\bar{b})=f(\overline{a+b})=e^{2\pi i(a+b)}=e^{2\pi ia}*e^{2\pi ib}=f(\bar{a})*f(\bar{b})$, so $f$ is a group-homomorphism.

---

I'm wondering whether my proof is correct. I was thinking this might be too simple or missing some crucial steps. I'm also not sure about the operations for the groups, I guessed that of $U_1$ would be multiplication as their elements come from $\mathbb{C}^*$, but the homomorphism only made sense if the operation on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ would be addition. Any tips?

Comment: it's correct! The operations are the ones you used, you can even show that it will be an isomorphism (since it's a bijection).

Comment: @TheGiraffeGuy thank you for your answer! I was almost afraid nobody would answer, haha. Do you have any tips on finding the operation on a certain group when it's not given (as in this case)? Sometimes it just makes sense but in other cases it might be harder.

Comment: A Group is by definition a set $G$, with a binary operation satisfying some axioms, so if you only give me G it's not a group, but just a set. For an exercise to be completely clear it should always explicitly tell you what group operation it's considering. In some cases, when it's not mentioned, we're considering the usual operation, for example in $\mathbb{R}$ it's the sum and therefore the group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has the induced operation. In the case of $U_1$ you should expect that the operation is either the sum or multiplication from $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: But it can't be the sum, since $(U_1,+)$ is not a group (you can easily verify that)

Comment: @The Giraffe Guy how can you say that the function is one to one? It is clearly not.

Comment: @Burak why is it not? If you have $f(\bar{a}) = f(\bar{b})$, it means that $e^{2\pi i a} = e^{2\pi i b} \implies e^{2\pi i (a-b)} = 1 \implies a-b = k$ , for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, which means $a+\mathbb{Z} = (b+k) + \mathbb{Z} = b + \mathbb{Z}$, in other words $\bar{a} = \bar{b}$, so the function is 1-1. And the fact that it is onto is pretty straightforward.